# How to Validate vue-ctk-date-time-picker using vuetify in Vuejs with rules?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to apply required validation for `vue-ctk-date-time-picker` using `:rules`.

Its Working for other elements but not working `with vue-ctk-date-time-picker`

Please correct me.

Here is the script that i am trying

```
dateTimePickerRules: [(v) => !!v || 'This Field is required'],



<vue-ctk-date-time-picker
    id="RangeDatePicker"
    v-model="tempInterpreterProjectDate"
    classname="form-control"
    color="dodgerblue"
    :only-date="true"
    :no-shortcuts="true"
    format="YYYY-MM-DD"
    formatted="ddd, MM/DD/YYY"
    :range="true"
    :rules="dateTimePickerRules"
    @input="selectedInterperateDate"
></vue-ctk-date-time-picker>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to validate `vue-ctk-date-time-picker` as follwing.

```
<ValidationObserver ref="dateTimeRef">
    <ValidationProvider
        v-slot="{ errors }"
        name="Date/time"
        rules="required"
    >
        <vue-ctk-date-time-picker
        id="RangeDatePicker"
        v-model="tempInterpreterProjectDate"
        classname="form-control"
        color="dodgerblue"
        :only-date="true"
        :no-shortcuts="true"
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        formatted="ddd, MM/DD/YYY"
        :error-messages="errors"
        :range="true"
        @input="selectedInterperateDate"
        ></vue-ctk-date-time-picker>
        <span class="v-messages theme--light error--text">{{
        errors[0]
        }}</span>
    </ValidationProvider>
</ValidationObserver>
```

I am validating this field something like this

```
// it will return eithter true or false
const isDateTimeValid = await this.$refs.dateTimeRef.validate()
```

Answer (score 0):

`vue-ctk-date-time-picker` is not a Vuetify component. There is no such [property](https://github.com/chronotruck/vue-ctk-date-time-picker#props-api) as `rules`. You need to implement a custom validation, e.g. on form submit (check if `tempInterpreterProjectDate` has a value)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have found the solution and answered below